# Редактор HTML и CSS на сайте

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html5

Хотел узнать каким образом html код можно из текстового редактора передать в блок,и он там отобразился ?, например как на сайте хтмлакадемии (не реклама). Я смею предположить, что это может быть Iframe в который передается html текст по нажатию на кнопку средставами js, но как передать туда css? Возможно написал глупость, поправьте пожалуйста

Answer (score 0):

Сайт хтмлакадемии использует [ace editor](https://ace.c9.io/#nav=about). Его можно испльзовать и для редактирования JS и для CSS

```js
 var editorJS = ace.edit("editorJS");
 editorJS.setTheme("ace/theme/monokai");
 editorJS.getSession().setMode("ace/mode/javascript");

 var editorCSS = ace.edit("editorCSS");
 editorCSS.setTheme("ace/theme/monokai");
 editorCSS.getSession().setMode("ace/mode/css");
```

```css
    #editorJS {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      right: 0;
      bottom: 50%;
      left: 0;
    }

    #editorCSS {
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      right: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/ace/1.2.6/min/ace.js"></script>
<div id="editorJS">
  function foo(items) {
  var x = "All this is syntax highlighted"; 
  return x;
  }
</div>

<div id="editorCSS">
      #editorJS {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      right: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
    }
</div>
```